# SQL join issue clarification

Tags: sql, coldfusion

I have two tables. client(clientid, company, state, status) and supportstatus(clientid, company, status, agreement). Shouldn't the following query return all companies who have an agreement value of 0 and whose status doesn't equal 'disabled'?
I'm confused because I'm selecting company, I'm joining, the two tables by the common factor(clientid), and I'm filtering the results of the query.

```
SELECT cl.company
FROM   clients cl
       INNER JOIN supportstatus su
         ON cl.clientid = su.clientid
WHERE  su.agreement11 = 0
       AND su.status <> 'disabled'
ORDER  BY cl.company
```

ColdFusion Source

```
<cfquery name="qryPendingAgreement" datasource="support">
SELECT clientid
FROM supportstatus
WHERE agreement11 = 0 AND status <> 'disabled'
</cfquery>

<cfquery name="qryClient" datasource="support">
SELECT     clientid, company, state, serv_billing
FROM         clients
WHERE prod_arth = 1 OR prod_artr = 1 OR prod_epcr_host = 1 OR prod_epcr_remote = 1 OR prod_billing = 1 OR prod_collections = 1
</cfquery>

<cfquery name="qryResults" dbtype="query">
SELECT qryClient.company, qryClient.state, qryClient.serv_billing
FROM qryPendingAgreement, qryClient
WHERE qryPendingAgreement.clientid = qryClient.clientid
order by qryClient.company
</cfquery>
```

Comment: Not sure what your question is? If it is not returning the results you expect provide example source data and desired results.

Comment: What exactly is happening with the result that is unexpected? The query is well formed.

Comment: Along the lines of what @MartinSmith said and can su.status contain NULL values?

Comment: What are you seeing that is different from what you expect?  Possible problems with your query are 1) you use column `agreement11`, you mentioned column `agreement` and 2) you're checking the `status` field in `supportstatus`, are you *looking* at the `status` field in `client`?

Comment: @MasterP: The two versions you have provided are **not** equivalent. The CF version has affitional filters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a wild guess but if you are using this version:

```
SELECT cl.company
FROM   clients cl
       INNER JOIN supportstatus su
         ON cl.clientid = su.clientid
WHERE  su.agreement11 = 0
       AND su.status <> 'disabled'
       OR prod_arth = 1      OR prod_artr = 1 
       OR prod_epcr_host = 1 OR prod_epcr_remote = 1 
       OR prod_billing = 1   OR prod_collections = 1
ORDER  BY cl.company
```

the issue is the `AND`, `OR` precedence. Try this:

```
SELECT cl.company
FROM   clients cl
       INNER JOIN supportstatus su
         ON cl.clientid = su.clientid
WHERE  su.agreement11 = 0
       AND su.status <> 'disabled'
       AND ( prod_arth = 1      OR prod_artr = 1 
          OR prod_epcr_host = 1 OR prod_epcr_remote = 1 
          OR prod_billing = 1   OR prod_collections = 1
           )
ORDER  BY cl.company
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say what results the query was giving you.  If the query is filtering more rows than you think it should, the answer might be three-valued logic.

`null != 'disabled'` -> `null`, which is not true and the row gets filtered.

Try this filter instead.

```
WHERE  su.agreement11 = 0
    AND isnull(su.status,'') <> 'disabled'
```

Comment: sorry. Yes, my query returns 5 more results than the CF version

Comment: @MasterP, the CF query has additional filters: `prod_arth = 1 OR  ...`

Comment: SELECT cl.company FROM clients cl INNER JOIN supportstatus su ON cl.clientid = su.clientid WHERE su.agreement11 = 0 AND isnull(su.status, '') <> 'disabled' Order By cl.company = Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'isnull'

Comment: when i add the addtional prod_arth info I get many more results I don't need.

Comment: a) my answer is aimed at TSQL.  You aren't using TSQL so it won't work for you.  b) my answer is aimed at the query text you posted.  You aren't using that query text so it won't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you test your query. Your question wasn't specific enough, so, this is the best I can do :)

```
    DECLARE @client TABLE
    (
      clientid int,
      company VARCHAR(50)
    )
    DECLARE @supportstatus TABLE
    (
      clientid int,
      [status] VARCHAR(50),
      agreement INT
    )

    INSERT INTO @client ([clientid],[company]) VALUES ( 0,'acme' ) 
    INSERT INTO @client ([clientid],[company]) VALUES ( 1,'byron' ) 
    INSERT INTO @client ([clientid],[company]) VALUES ( 2,'cathode' ) 

    INSERT INTO @supportstatus ([clientid],[status], agreement) VALUES ( 0, 'disabled',0)
    INSERT INTO @supportstatus ([clientid],[status], agreement) VALUES ( 0, 'disabled',1)
    INSERT INTO @supportstatus ([clientid],[status], agreement) VALUES ( 0, 'somethingelse',0)
    INSERT INTO @supportstatus ([clientid],[status], agreement) VALUES ( 0, 'somethingelse',1)

    INSERT INTO @supportstatus ([clientid],[status], agreement) VALUES ( 1, 'disabled',0)
    INSERT INTO @supportstatus ([clientid],[status], agreement) VALUES ( 1, 'disabled',1)
    --INSERT INTO @supportstatus ([clientid],[status], agreement) VALUES ( 1,   'somethingelse',0)
    --INSERT INTO @supportstatus ([clientid],[status], agreement) VALUES ( 1,   'somethingelse',1)

    --INSERT INTO @supportstatus ([clientid],[status], agreement) VALUES ( 2,   'disabled',0)
    INSERT INTO @supportstatus ([clientid],[status], agreement) VALUES ( 2, 'disabled',1)
    --INSERT INTO @supportstatus ([clientid],[status], agreement) VALUES ( 2,   'somethingelse',0)
    INSERT INTO @supportstatus ([clientid],[status], agreement) VALUES ( 2, 'somethingelse',1)

    -- all companies who have su.agreement = 0 and su.status <> 'disabled' 
    SELECT cl.company 
    FROM @client cl 
    JOIN @supportstatus su ON cl.clientid = su.clientid 
    WHERE su.agreement = 0 AND su.status <> 'disabled' 
    Order By cl.company
```